# Laravel / Voyager creating event not firing in User model

Tags: laravel, events, voyager

I am trying to insert some logic when the 'creating' event is fired in the User model of a Laravel/Voyager application, here's my code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{ 
use Notifiable;

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // over-ride the creating event
    static::creating(function($user)
    {
      $user->created_by = auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null;
    });

    // over-ride the updating event
    static::updating(function($user)
    {
      $user->updated_by = auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null;
    });
}
```

}

But it looks like the 'creating' event is never called, while the 'boot' method is called.
Anyone has got any idea why ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that will be stuck in the same situation: you have to tell Voyager which model/class to use in the BREAD settings, otherwise Voyager will always use \TCG\Voyager\Models\User .